# Extensão para o Chrome não executa

Tags: google-chrome-extensão

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Gmail Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Share your mail from Gmail on facebook.",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "gmail.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "page":"background.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

background.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=326350284188834&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou a tentar fazer uma extensão do Chrome para que os utilizadores possam partilhar os seus emails do gmail no facebook.

Acontece que ao importar para as extensões do Chrome não acontece nada. 
O que estou a fazer mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A principio a extensão funcionou normalmente e faz *exatamente o que você pede* no seu manifest, ele cria um botão com um ícone e nada mais, veja a imagem:

[image: exemplo de extensão no chrome]

Acredito que o que você queira é usar os pop-ups das extensões.

No caso você adicionou o seu HTML ao `background`, isso quer dizer que ele vai rodar, mas não vai ser exibido. O correto seria usar [`browser_action.default_popup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

O seu manifest deve ser algo como:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Gmail Extension test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Share your mail from Gmail on facebook.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "gmail.png",
        "default_popup":"background.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

Note que você deve alterar está linha

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=326350284188834&version=v2.0";
```

para

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=326350284188834&version=v2.0";
```

Note que o seu html está causando um problema de segurança (leia em https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion):

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Você deve mover o javascript para um arquivo JS isolado e chama-lo assim:

```
<script src="meu-javascript.js"></script>
```

E no caso como você está usando uma extensão externa vinda do dominio `http://connect.facebook.com.br`, você deverá adicionar ao manifest isto:

```
{
...
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://*.facebook.net; object-src 'self'"
}
```

### Por onde começar

Você deve iniciar os seus estudos usando a documentação [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) (está em inglês, mas no Chrome você pode traduzir --não vai ficar perfeito mas ajuda)